# Did IE8 lose the document.frames collection?

Tags: javascript, scripting, internet-explorer-8

I noticed that an application I am maintaining was giving me a javascript error in IE8 and FF. The script was trying to get a collection of frame elements:

```
document.frames
```

This always returned 'undefined'. I placed a watch on the document object and noticed that this collection does not seem to be a member of the document object in IE8. I think this was always the case in FF but this same code works in older versions of IE. Has this been removed?

-Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=186831) discussion:

> frames is a property of window and does not have to be addressable via document, but I.E. makes it available.

So IE made it possible before, but not any more